# How can I encrypt just a single table data in redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can I encrypt just a single table data in redshift database?

I see that encryption is a cluster level setting. But I need to encrypt just 1 table and not all the tables of the database.

I have user personal information in the table that I want to encrypt.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is your use-case for requiring encryption on only one table? We might be able to suggest something else. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: What are the particular rules you are trying to satisfy by encrypting the table? This might impact the definition of "encryption". Redshift encryption is "encryption at rest", but it is still accessible by authorised users. What are your specific requirements that need to be met?

Answer (score 0):

No. As you say, encryption is a cluster-level setting.

You could encrypt the data in the table yourself, but this makes it hard to write useful SQL queries.